# select categories where their parent is type 1

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table categories

```
|catId  |catName|catParentID|catType|
-------------------------------------
|1      |cat1   |null       |6      |
|2      |cat2   |null       |9      |
|3      |cat3   |1          |6      |
|4      |cat4   |2          |9      |
|5      |cat5   |1          |6      | 
|6      |cat6   |3          |8      |
```

the parents are in the same table with the sub categories only they have no parent.

i need to get all the sub categories that their parent's type is 6.

the output of the example above should look like this-

```
cat3
cat5
```

Comment: #6 should also be returned as well based on your description of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your data structure, this seems to work:

```
select c.*
from categories c
where c.catParentID is not null and -- has a parent
      c.catType = 6;
```

However, that might not be a general solution.  So you can use a self-join:

```
select c.*
from categories c join
     categories cp
     on c.catParentID = cp.catID
where cp.catType = 6;
```

Comment: select categories where their parent is type 1?  what it means?

Comment: well base on my example you seems to be right.. but in the original table there is a lot of sub categories that their catType is null.. so i need to take the type from the parent..

Comment: what will be the output if catName `cat6`  is having `6` catType . Is this row is selected or not?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM   categories
WHERE  cattype = 6
       AND catparentid IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

The Simplest way is,

```
SELECT * FORM categories WHERE catParentId ='1' AND catType ='6'
```

Comment: I think this one is right ans. Question and description is too much confusing

Answer (score 0):

Try this... (Based on your desired output)

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM   tablename t1
       LEFT JOIN tablename t2 ON t1.catparentid = t2.catid
WHERE  t2.cattype = 6
       AND t2.catparentid IS NULL
```